# Why praying is not a compulsion in Hinduism?

Tags: prayer, dharma

In some religions like Christanity and Islam there are some forced praying time. Christians have to attend mass in weekends (sundays) whereas muslims congregates on fridays in mosques. As far I know there is no forced praying time in hinduism.

Why doesn't Hinduism follow these kind of strict rules or does it have any such praying rule?

Comment: I think its more of a personal view rather than religion thing.

Comment: @Eka: In islam you can also skip Namaz but that is only if the reason is physical disability!!!

Comment: Free will plays a bigger part in Hinduism than 'obedience' and 'fear' to God.

Comment: Hinduism itself is a WAY OF LIVING. Each individual can make a choice on their quality of living!(whether to pray or not)

Comment: Because hinduism is not a sect. There is no one kind of religion we can call Hinduism. We are just letting it be a convention to refer to ancient Indian philosophies being Hindu. Whereas there is no Hindu in reality.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You used an Important word called Force (I will not talk about the scientific force here)

> **Force ( Meaning ) :** 
>   1. Coercion or compulsion, especially with the use or threat of violence.
>   2. Make (someone) do something against their will.

**What is Will :** The thing that one desires(and the desire is limited to natural cause, e.g. You had a full meal, but you want to have more, its greed not will).

Hinduism teaches to *move in parallel to nature*, this is only thing which Hinduism calls to human, and the first principle of walking parallel to nature is doing with your will.

Hinduism believes in Karma, you have your will, do whatever you want, but be prepare for the consequences. Doesn't it looks logical and more natural, a lion never eats with full stomach, neither any animal. Its nature, we are nature, if we force someone against the will, we are actually forcing the nature.

The only thing we can do is teach them the *difference between right and wrong*, its always a *person's choice to choose one*.

***Now about Pray :***
What is Pray ? Is pray limited to group of words, which you draft in-front of god. No in Hinduism it has a broader concept, if your Praying just the sake of Drafting words its useless, you need to do with your will, you should have an utter belief in him, you should be ready and gone from other thoughts while you are praying him.

If you pray with your will you are actually thoughtless and your pure intentions are inclined towards him, making it more effective.

***Are their rules for Praying***(I shouldn't use the word here as its with limited sence) : Their are rules, like ***Surya Namashkar*, which will be helpful in *Brahmamuhurata* only**. But they are not forced to us, why ? again its your will if you want to gain the benefits or not.

***What GOD wants :*** Is he a dictator? no he is a creator, to understand this, just think you created something, you will love to be it what you created. Therefore GOD doesn't wants you to Pray him, if you do he will Please, but If you don't it will not hurt him, *he only wants you to take care of the fellow creation*.

My answers may feel empty without scriptural proofs, I will try to add some, but this is the overview of Hinduism.

Answer (score 9):

The reason is given in Gita 18.63 which says,

> ...Reflecting on this entire teaching do as you think fit.

A Hindu might well not agree with Hindu spiritual teachings. Compulsory praying will go against the liberal spirit of the Gita.

Answer (score 6):

**TL;DR: Prayer is a duty if you wear the sacred thread.**

The daily [Sandhyavandanam](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sandhyavandanam) ritual is the duty of wearers of the sacred thread, and as I discuss in my answer, the wearing of the sacred thread is the duty of all Dvijas (members of the first three castes).

[Chapter 2](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/manu/manu02.htm) of the Manu Smriti includes a discussion the various duties of Dvijas; here is what it says about the duty of the daily chanting of the Gayatri mantra, which is the central activity of the Sandhyavandhanam ritual:

> 101. Let him stand during the morning twilight, muttering the Savitri until the sun appears, but (let him recite it), seated, in the evening until the constellations can be seen distinctly.
> 102. He who stands during the morning twilight muttering (the Savitri), removes the guilt contracted during the (previous) night; but he who (recites it), seated, in the evening, destroys the sin he committed during the day.
> 103. **But he who does not (worship) standing in the morning, nor sitting in the evening, shall be excluded, just like a Sudra, from all the duties and rights of an Arya.**

Note that the Gayatri mantra is called the Savitri here because it's a mantra to Surya, and Savita is another name for Surya.

Answer (score 4):

Hiduisam is very broad religion, covers all levels of peoples based on spritual. The mantra one chants is actually a prayer. 
Example

> hare kṛṣṇa hare kṛṣṇa
>   kṛṣṇa kṛṣṇa hare hare
>   hare rāma hare rāma
>   rāma rāma hare hare

means Oh Lord please engage me in your service. Chanting mantra consciously is itself a prayer

Further

All the grievous sins are removed for one who worships Lord Sri Hari, the Lord of all lords, and chants the holy name, the Maha-mantra.
— Padma Purana, 3.50.6

If one chants consciously one gets benefit, rather forcing someone to chant and chanting unconsciously.